# Why does Django ModelForm change it's internal instance object before save() call.. sometimes?

Tags: python, django

In my custom `UpdateView` I'd like to compare the field content of form with fields of object which this form is supposed to change (it was given as `instance` argument to form constructor and also saved as `self.object`). I tried this in `form_valid() method`:

```
if self.object.content != form.save(commit=False).content
   ...
```

and this

```
if self.object.content != form.cleaned_data['content']
   ....
```

In both cases this test does not pass cause both values are equal. Hmm.. it became interesting and I did some simple tests in django shell to double check this behavior. Actually I got some really awkward results then. Check this out:

```
>>> class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
...     class Meta:
...         model=Article
...         fields = ('title',)

>>> a = Article.objects.all()[0]
>>> a
<Article: 12345>
>>> form = ArticleForm(data={'title': 'python-power'}, instance=a)
>>> a
<Article: python-power>

>>> a = Article.objects.all()[0]
>>> a
<Article: 12345>
>>> form = ArticleForm(data={'title': 'python-power'}, instance=a)
>>> a
<Article: 12345>
```

Is it normal at all? Why I need save method (especially with commit=True) if instance object is changed anyway... well sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

As described in django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

> If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn't yet been saved to the database. In this case, it's up to you to call save() on the resulting model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the specialized model saving options. commit is True by default

The Instance is only updated but it is not yet saved to the database. You need to call `save` method to transfer those changes to database.